# GoogleTagManager integration issue - Internal error - Function call: __fm_validateEventData

Tags: android, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

I have integrated GoogleTagManager in project, I am sending a dummy event with basic Params.

Event details -

```
firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this)
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "my_item_id")
firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle)
```

But getting this issue -

```
Event does not have parameter "item_id" and no default value was defined. Returning "undefined".
Event does not have parameter "test1" and no default value was defined. Returning "undefined".
Internal error - Function call: __fm_validateEventData
Apply TypeError: object has no charAt property
```

Same event is working in demo project.